# "Variable 'xxx' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant" ERROR

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I have the following problem. I use this code below and I get the issue

> "Variable 'characteristic' was never mutated; consider changing to
>   'let' constant"

```
for var characteristic:CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics ?? [] {
    print(str)
    _selectedPeripheral!.writeValue(str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
}
```

When I change to "let", there's an Error:

> 'let' pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable context

Why does it recommend me the change and afterwards mark it as an error?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You just need to remove `var`, making your code:

```
for characteristic in service.characteristics ?? [] {
    print(str)
    _selectedPeripheral!.writeValue(str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
}
```

because `characteristic` is immutable by default.

Comment: Thanks for your supported.